# How to click an image with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click this button, but the button is actually an image which doesn't have an ID. I've tried using the Xpath by doing

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a"))
).click()
```

but this wasn't able to find the element. Any help would be great! Here's the relevant HTML

```
<a class="navcontent" href=f5-h-$$/MSL/jsp/openGimPage.jsp?gimEnv=GIM&amp;ep=GIMV" target="blank>
<img onclick="F5_r2u();F5_Event_common(event);try{return(eval(F5_Invoke_eval_event(null,F5_jsBody(function(){parent.trackUserActivity(this,'o','Portlet : Incident Management '+(this.src).split('/images/')[1].split('.')[0]);
<p id="text" style="top: 7px">View</p></a>
```

Edit: Here is the remainder of the HTML
[Remainder of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v55Mt.png)

Comment: I don't think you can click <a> tags. You should try clicking the div or whatever else is holding the <a>

Comment: I edited to add the remainder of the HTML

Comment: maybe you can just extract href attribute from a tag and then just navigate to that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. As KunduK pointed out, it was within an iFrame. I had to use the following to select the iFrame, then click the button within.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following `xpath` to identify the element. Use `element_to_be_clickable`()
instead `presence_of_element_located`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[./p[text()='View']]"))).click()
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Temp\ATMStatusScript.py1\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: The element must be inside iframe? Can you check Dom? If it is there you need to switch it?

Comment: Sorry, but how would I go about checking the Dom to find out if it's in an iframe?

Comment: Actually I found it. Do you know how to reference it? <iframe src="includes/homepage/incidentMgmt.jsp" width="324" height="265"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion. I also had this question,and solved by Tyler's way. But I used code below to solved the problem.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))    
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="XPATH")
```